# My If-Statement runs without getting the needed imput?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
Touch touchForThrow;

void Update()
    {
        if (Input.touchCount > 0)
            touchForThrow = Input.GetTouch(1);

        if (touchForThrow.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        {
            Debug.Log(Input.touchCount);
        }
    }
```

The second If-statement is running without a touch imput. **touchForThrow.phase == TouchPhase.Began** should not be possible, even the Debug.Log says that 0 touches are identified, but it still runs the statement.

Comment: Please provide the definitions for `Touch` and `TouchPhase`. If statements in .NET _are not broken_.

Comment: TouchPhase describes the phase of a finger touch. Touch is a touch that you specify. Hope that is what you mean.

Comment: They are Unity types.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realise they were Unity types. The [sample here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Touch-phase.html) doesn't compare `phase` unless `Input.touchCount > 0`. Perhaps `TouchPhase.Began` is the default value of `phase`?

Comment: You a right sir. TouchPhase.Began is the default value of phase. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are waiting for **one** touch but are trying to get the **second** one! Remember that indices in c# are 0-based!

Also [`Touch`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Touch.html) is a struct and thereby always has a default value. Even if your first `if` is not true it already has a dummy touch value where the phase might be `Began` by default.

It should probably rather be

```
if (Input.touchCount > 0)
{
    touchForThrow = Input.GetTouch(0);

    if(touchForThrow.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
    {
        Debug.Log(Input.touchCount);
    }
 }
```

---

If you want the **second** touch you should probably rather first check if there are at least two touches

```
if(Input.touchCount > 1)
```

Comment: My intention was to get the second touch, because there is a first touch for the movement.

Comment: That removes my Index out of bounds error. Really helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

TouchPhase.Began is the default value of phase.
The code worked properly, after nesting the second If-statement in the first one.